# Changing background color hovering over different li a

Tags: html, css

I got my navigation bar to work nicely but I need to have different colors in the backgrounds of each element.
I tried giving them ID's and using it in CSS but it doesn't work.
The "info day"should be firebrick(red) but "course"and "locations" should be two different colors.
Can anyone one help me out?

```css
.menuUl {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}
.menuLi {
  float: left;
  border: none;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: firebrick;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menuUl">
  <li class="menuLi" id="courses"><a class="active" href="EindOpdracht.html">COURSES</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menuLi" id="infoDay"><a href="">INFO DAY</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menuLi" id="locations"><a href="Location.html">LOCATIONS</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're saying you gave them IDs but that didn't help. You did put IDs in, but you are not using the IDs in your CSS. It's not really clear what you want to do. Your CSS says it should have a red background on mouseover (`:hover`). That's what it does. There is no other `background-color` anywhere, so it's white the rest of the time.

Comment: the question is not clear

Comment: I did use it but I took the code away. It looks like it is white on white but I only hsowed the CSS code that I needed help with. The entire page has a background that makes everything very visible.

Comment: @Oriel.F The question was very clear, clear enough to get the right answer from Anuja

Comment: take a look at what @simbabque write to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I change their font-color for visibility in the snippet-demo but the main idea is to use them like this `li#infoDay a:hover`. Its specific to id's and changing their order wont affect the css

```css
.menuUl{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}
.menuLi{
    float: left;
    border: none;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
    
    border-radius: 5px;
}
li#courses a:hover{
  background-color: blue;
}
li#locations a:hover{
  background-color: green;
}
li#infoDay a:hover{
  background-color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="menuUl">
    <li class="menuLi" id="courses"><a class="active" href="EindOpdracht.html">COURSES</a></li>
    <li class="menuLi" id="infoDay"><a href="">INFO DAY</a></li>
    <li class="menuLi" id="locations"><a href="Location.html">LOCATIONS</a></li>
</ul>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Hope this helpful:

```css
.menuUl{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}
.menuLi{
    float: left;
    border: none;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li:nth-child(1) a:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
li:nth-child(2) a:hover {
    background-color: firebrick;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
li:nth-child(3) a:hover {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menuUl">
    <li class="menuLi" id="courses"><a class="active" href="EindOpdracht.html">COURSES</a></li>
    <li class="menuLi" id="infoDay"><a href="">INFO DAY</a></li>
    <li class="menuLi" id="locations"><a href="Location.html">LOCATIONS</a></li>
</ul>
```